# SSIS Deployment Wizard - Select Destination Page - User name and Password controls disabled

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and am working my way through some tutorials and examples from a book I've purchased, so bear with me if this is a basic question.  My test environment - VMWare VM with 24 GB RAM with SQL Server 2017 Developer on Windows 10 Pro.  SSMS 17.8.1 and Visual Studio 15 Update 3, SSDT 14.0.61712.050 - all running on the same VM.

I've tried running the Deployment Wizard from SSMS and from VS - both give the same result. On the Select Source page, the deployment model is Project Deployment & the .ispac Project deployment file is selected.  So far, so good.  When I get to the Select Destination page, my local SQL server is selected, Windows Authentication is selected (as it must be, as I understand it), but the User name and Password controls are disabled. Nothing I've tried has affected the enabled setting for these controls.

I've read all the SSIS related questions on this site and have scoured the internet for days, trying to find a solution for this.  Based on my lack of success, I'm wondering if this configuration is even supported.

Any thoughts or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

BTW - I don't know if this is related, but I'm also seeing very slow performance connecting to this instance of SQL Server using Windows Authentication from SSMS.  Connection is instantaneous using SQL authentication.  I spent a couple days chasing that around, too.  This is a stand-alone box - not connected to a domain.  I work remotely, so I do connect to the corporate network via VPN. It seems to be related to DNS (or reverse DNS), as adding an entry in my HOSTS file (computer-name  127.0.0.1) significantly reduced connection time (still slow, but faster than before) and connection time is slower when VPN is connected (connecting to VPN adds two DNS server addresses).

[Image of SSIS Deployment Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdZVz.png)

Answer (score 1):

"Windows Authentication" means "Windows Integrated Authentication", so you connect to the server "as yourself" without supplying additional credentials. The "User name" and "Password" fields will only get enabled when not using Windows Authentication. I guess that you are wondering how to specify the target location on the server. Well, although "Windows Authentcation" is pre-selected, it isn't "done" yet. You will have to click on "connect" to make it happen.

As for the slow performance while beeing connected via VPN: Yes, it is for sure a DNS problem. While connected to the corporate network, you will use a DNS server from the company network first, and those DNS servers do not know the name of your private computer. An entry in the "hosts" file will help, but I suggest to use just a single dot (`.`) instead of your hostname when connecting to your local SQL Server.